# How to ignore property when using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

i have a public property in my class, how should I mark it (some attribute) to be ignored when following flags are given

```
BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
BindingFlags.Instance | 
BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
BindingFlags.Public
```

I need to use method from dll with parameters: object and binding flags, so i need to mark my property somehow to be ignored by this method

Comment: Cant you just skip it when you are itterating the properties?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to specify when to ignore, I would recommend you either use a parameter in your API for the user to specify which property to ignore, or use a custom attribute that indicates it should be ignored. Or, are you saying the answer must follow these flags and only these flags?

Comment: @Magnus no cos i use method from dll :D

Comment: Cant you use a custom attribute ?

Comment: @kosnkov: what method? what dll?

Comment: I have to admit I get pretty annoyed when everyone on SO answers questions by telling the OP their initial question is wrong. People should at least address the question verbatim, as well as give an alternative solution to what might be the real issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing the roles of BindingFlags and CustomAttributes. BindingFlags find things based on whether they are `private`, `static`, etc.

If you want to ignore a property in your consuming code, you'll need to change that consuming code to ignore properties with a particular custom attribute associated with them.

If you don't have access to the consuming code, there isn't any way to make it not see a property that is there. There may be some workarounds depending on how the code is written, though. For example, if the code is searching based on a specific type argument, you could create an abstract base class to house all the properties you want it to care about, and then extend that class for your actual implementation, adding some extra properties for your convenience.

Or you could create a DTO to represent just the properties you want to convey to the method you're calling, and copy the appropriate properties from your original object into that DTO.

Comment: I would have agreed completely if he hadn't ended his question with "when following flags are given". Do note that my comment on his question addresses this point that you are making. Also, hi :)

Comment: Given his flags, there is a way as his flags would not pick up statics.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior i am not sure how works parsing properites by reflection but isn't that possible to mark some filds as "reflection! i am sepcial field don't look at me, keep going" ?? and what if would give to that method all possible binding flags? then there is not other way to still ignore some then to change modeling??

Comment: @payo: I get the impression that he probably doesn't want to change the behavior of his object (by making a property static).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior sure i don't want to, that would be the last thing i want to

Comment: @kosnkov: No, there isn't any way to mark a field to be ignored by reflection generally. The people who wrote the method that uses reflection would have to have provided you with an API that allows you to flag properties to be ignored by that framework. That's what most serialization/deserialization frameworks do, for instance.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior ok so i probably do another class with that field inherit from it, this will works with flag BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly, ok thanks. I could use custom attribute, but as i told i can't change that method to read properties out.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior touche - to me the question was more "what does this not find". I suppose I'm guilty as well of filling in ambiguities with my own interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Your flags will not return static properties.

```
class Foo
{
  public static int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT** You have stated you don't want to change behavior. Does your dll take an object or a type? If a type, you could use inheritance to 'hide' your properties from this method.

Say you have right now:

```
class Foo
{
  public int X {get;set;}
  public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

And your code expect `Foo` to have `X` and `Y`. If your dll/utility takes types, then we can make `Foo` derive `Bar`. Let's say we don't want the utility to see 'X', but only 'Y'.

```
class Bar
{
  public int Y {get;set;}
}

class Foo : Bar
{
  public int X {get;set;}
}
```

// in your utility call

```
utility.Baz(foo.GetType().BaseType); // <- Base here is Bar, which does not have X
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ignore it during the call is to use `Type.FindMembers`, but that will probably require more work than just post filtering it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom attribute would be appropriate here. Decorate the members you wish to ignore with the attribute, and wrap the code you're using to inspect the properties in a routine that would weed out the decorated items.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetNonPublicProperties(this Type t) {
        return t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(prop => prop.GetAccessors(true).Where(mi => mi.IsPublic == false).Count() != 0).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then just use `Type.GetNonPublicProperties` and you're set.